# Как получить данные из ajax запроса на сервере node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

Есть ajax запрос:

```
$.get('/test', {name : 'Vasya'});
```

Как на сервере node.js с использованием библиотеки express, получить значение name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

  // Получаем параметры GET-запроса
  let name = req.query.name

  console.log(name) // Vasya

  res.send({user_name: name})
})


app.listen(3000)
```

Запускаете: `node app.js`, делаете запросы по пути [`http://localhost:3000/test`](http://localhost:3000/test), можете через браузер зайти и проверить (запрос же `GET`).

Передаваемые при `GET` запросе параметры `{ name: 'Vasya' }` будут преобразованы `jQuery` в `/test?name=Vasya`, а получать эти параметры (которые находятся в `query` запроса) нужно с помощью `req.query`. Если бы это был `$.post`, тогда через `req.body`.

Comment: @ЭльдарЮсупжанов почитайте чуть больше про теорию, что такое `GET` и `POST`-запрос, чем они отличаются, как отправлять такие запросы, и потом уже не будет вопросов, как их обрабатывать.